# Looking for a word meaning small/petite

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, adjectives, synonyms

Help I’m drawing a blank! 
Looking for a word that describes a person as having a small build and also fits into the sentence “*she was a _______ of a woman*”

Comment: Probably "a slip of a woman" - an outdated expression, which might not pass muster with the political correctness tsar.

Comment: @WS2 - How so?  Someone can be a *slip of a boy*.

Comment: You might want to add to your question that none of the surrounding text of your example sentence can be altered in order to accommodate the word. (At least it seems to me that's why both *small* and *petite* don't fit. If that's not why you've rejected them, then you need to explain what's wrong with them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh yes, I believe you are looking for "wisp" as in, "a wisp of a girl", or in the case of your sentence, woman.

Merriam-Webster's definition [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisp).

Answer (score 0):

As in:

“she was a [dainty](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dainty) woman”

> 1. Delicately beautiful or charming and usually small: